# Find, update an element and change its index in array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, higher-order-functions, reducers

What I am trying to achieve here is for a Chat App where the last conversation (between the current logged in user and the target user) should update its lastMessage and be placed at the first position in the conversations array.

Here is a simpler version of the conversations array:

```
const conversations = [
    { ... },
    {
        _id: 5,
        lastMessage: {
            sender: 1
            receiver: 2
            message: 'Hello World',
            conversation_id: 5
        }
    },
    { ... }
]
```

If the user with `id = 1` sends a message to the user with `id = 2` it should update the conversation with `_id = 5` and move it to index 0 of the conversations array.

What I currently have done is moving the conversation to the top of the array but I cannot figure out how to change its lastMessage. (React reducer)

```
conversations: [state.conversations.find(el => el._id === action.payload.conversation_id), ...state.conversations.filter(el => el._id !== action.payload.conversation_id)]
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this meet your requirements?

```
// find the first convo as you already do
const firstConversation = state.conversations
          .find(el => el._id === action.payload.conversation_id);

// this is the current `lastMessage`
const lastMessage = {...first.lastMessage};

// make changes to `lastMessage` here, or assign a completely new object as required
const firstConversationUpdated = {...firstConversation, lastMessage: lastMessage};

// update state below
conversations: [firstConversationUpdated, 
                ...state.conversations.filter(el => el._id !== action.payload.conversation_id)]
```

Comment: My bad, here you go